# Write NoData in every line that has no data (python 3.x)

Tags: csv, python-3.x

Files look like this:

```
2014-01-01    a    a   a
2014-01-01    a        a
2014-01-01    a    a
```

i want to go through all rows and add `NoData` in empty rows:
 output should look like this:

```
2014-01-01    a    a   a
2014-01-01    a    NodData    a
2014-01-01    a    a    NoData
```

should I open files with `csv reader`and than loop through all lines? How can I define empty cell/ row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/input', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        row = [cell if cell else 'NoData' for cell in row]
        outfile.writerow(row)
```

If you want to overwrite the input file:

```
import csv

with open('path/to/input') as infile: rows = list(csv.reader(infile))
with open('path/to/input', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in ([cell if cell else 'NoData' for cell in row] for row in rows)
        outfile.writerow(row)
```

If you want to do this for all csv files in a directory:

```
import csv
import glob
import os

dirpath = "/Users/Kevin/Desktop/DataArena/"
for infilepath in glob.glob(os.path.join(dirpath, "*.csv")):
    with open(infilepath) as infile: rows = list(csv.reader(infile))
    with open(infilepath, 'w') as fout:
        outfile = csv.writer(fout)
        for row in ([cell if cell else 'NoData' for cell in row] for row in rows)
            outfile.writerow(row)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply so the `path/to/input` should be the path to the files I want to scan through? can I do something like `filename = infile` so that each file keeps the original name when being converted?

Comment: thanks again, I'm super bad with directories so for `/Users/Kevin/Desktop/DataArena/` as `path/to/input` is sufficient to catch all .csv files in folder

Comment: Thank you very much for you guidance :-) Awesome